# devtools::install_github("imbs-hl/ranger") fails - make.exe and sh.exe unable to start correctly

Tags: r, cygwin

I'm trying to install the development version of the R library ranger from RStudio on Windows 7 with the command:

```
devtools::install_github("imbs-hl/ranger")
```

When I try this, I first get a pop-up with the header "make.exe - Application Error" and the message "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)."

I then get a message saying that I need to install additional build tools. This downloads RTools. I then get an identical pop up like the make.exe one, except that this time it's for sh.exe. After I click ok, it then does a somewhat long install of RTools. The setup window closes and the development packages remain uninstalled.

**Note: when I run either sh.exe or make.exe from the windows command line, I get the same errors. This might have something to do with the fact that I have cygwin installed.**

I can get sh.exe and make.exe to run from the windows command line if I remove RTools from the path, leaving only cygwin. However, this doesn't change the problem I get when I try installing the development version of ranger.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple version on cygwin1.dll ? One in Rtools and one in Cygwin

Comment: That's possible. How does that help me? Should I replace the Rtools one with the Cygwin one?

Comment: My method for getting rid of errors like this was to avoid the cross-over that having both Rtools and cygwin presented. It's "bad enough" that git-for-windows is cygwin-based, though because it does not have the full range of unixy-tools, it usually is not a big deal. I'm assuming this is not an option for you, so ... consider removing cygwin from your path when running R stuff. In my `~/.Rprofile` file, I often had path-removing (or at least path-elevating) code so that Rtools always won.

Comment: I removed cygwin from both the user and system paths. Running the "where" command on sh or make clearly shows that the system is only aware of the Rtools versions. However, now I just get a different pop-up: "make.exe - System Error", with the text: "The program can't start because cygwin1.dll is missing from your computer. Try resinatlling the program to fix the problem."

Comment: The comments here were right. It had to do with cygwin. I decided to try renaming the cygwin folder. This caused RTools to be completely reinstalled, including the cygwin1.dll file which had not been installed by RTools when it thought that cygwin was installed on the computer.